# New node doesnt get properly added to end of linked list when adding through function

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to add new nodes to a linked list via a function to add nodes. But when i print the list it seems data in all nodes get replaced by the recently added data.

```
typedef struct things {
    char *string;
    struct things *next;
} something;

void addnode(something **head, char *str);
void printlist(something **head);

int main()
{
    int i;
    char word[50];
    something *head = NULL;

    puts("How many strings?");
    scanf("%d", &i);

    while(i > 0)
    {
        scanf("%49s", word);
        addnode(&head, word);
        i--;
    }

    printlist(&head);
    return 0;
}

void addnode(something **head, char *str)
{
    something *last = *head;
    something *newnode;

    newnode = malloc(sizeof(something));
    newnode->string = malloc(50*sizeof(char));
    newnode->string = str;
    newnode->next = NULL;

    if ((*head)==NULL)
    {
        (*head) = newnode;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        while(last->next != NULL)
        {
            last=last->next;
        }
        last->next = newnode;
        return;
    }
}
void printlist(something **head) //print contents of list, to check if list was created
{
    puts("print");
    something *current = *head;
    while(current != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", current->string);
        current=current->next;
    }
}
```

This is what i came up with. When i enter say 5 words `one` `two` `three` `four` `five`, i get the output `five five five five five`. Is this an issue with the way i'm trying to print? Or is it with how i'm passing the pointers and linking the nodes?

Comment: You have to copy the contents of `word` too. Now they all point to the same buffer `word` and so will all show the same value. :-)

Comment: `newnode->string = malloc(50*sizeof(char));
    newnode->string = str;` That is not the way to copy a string (plus: you leak memory here) Instead, use `strcpy()` (or `strdup()` the entire string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning pointers does not copy their contents. Just makes them to point to the same memory address.

In your code you are allocating memory for new node's `str` and you make it point to the buffer's address(`word` for your case). By doing this eventually all node's `str` will point to the contents the address of buffer's last value(five for your case).

```
newnode->string = malloc(50*sizeof(char));
newnode->string = str;
```

Another issue here is that you do not allocate memory dynamically based on the buffer's content.

To allocate exactly the required amount of memory try this:

Replace:

```
newnode->string = malloc(50*sizeof(char));
```

With:

```
 newnode->string = malloc((strlen(str)+1)*sizeof(char));
```

With `strlen` you get the number of characters and `+1` is for allocating space for terminating character `'\0'`.

So to fix your initial issue, you need to copy buffer's content to the newly allocated memory:

Replace:

```
newnode->string = str;
```

with

```
strcpy(newnode->string,str);
```

Comment: Please show the use of `strlen(str)+1` to allocate the exact amount of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Change insert function like,

```
void addnode(something **head, char *str)
{
    something *last = *head;
    something *newnode;

    newnode = malloc(sizeof(something));
    newnode->string = malloc(50*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(newnode->string, str);
    newnode->next = NULL;

    if ((*head)==NULL)
    {
        (*head) = newnode;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        while(last->next != NULL)
        {
            last=last->next;
        }
        last->next = newnode;
        return;
    }
}
```